# Combine 2 onClick events?

Tags: html

does anyone know how I can combine 2 onclick events?

```
<a href="#" onClick='return resetVideo("vid1;vid3")'>
```

I want to reset both videos'1' and '3' - but can't seem to get it to work! Do I have to include the resetVideo command twice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<a href="#" onClick='resetVideo("vid1"); resetVideo("vid3")'>
```

Comment: Thanks jodes - it works!! - I'm sure I had that at some point, I think I tried every variation - I appreciate your time!!

Answer (score 1):

You can put 'full' JavaScript code into an onclick-Attribute, so you can call multiple Functions:

```
<a href="#" onClick='resetVideo("vid1");resetVideo("vid3");return false;'>
```

Note: `return false` at the end is needed to ignore the `href` Attribute.

Comment: Thanks the additional comments Floern - learning as I go, all the help/advice I get on here has been brilliant!